anylogic in ubuntu
I install AnyLogic Professional in folder "Documents" in Ubuntu
and run it "wine AnyLogic.exe". Then  AnyLogic logo appeared but
then it stopped.
Any advice for resolve this issue?
Before running, I change folder in terminal to
AnyLogic folder

Not all Windows apps work well with Wine. What are you trying to do with AnyLogic? We can try to suggest an equivalent native software for Ubuntu.

Wine has a site that lists the supported apps and any know caveats. A good place to start.

The problem is solved by installing Gecko.
The easiest way:

Go to https://gitlab.winehq.org/wine/wine/-/wikis/Gecko.
Download wine-gecko-[version]-x86.msi and wine-gecko-[version]-x86_64.msi (these are the installers).
Go to the downloads folder and execute the commands wine wine-gecko-[version]-x86.msi and wine-gecko-[version]-x86_64.msi.

Anylogic should now load. It uses a browser for its operation, so it requires Gecko, which is an equivalent to Internet Explorer.
